# How can i get the duplicate value in oracle

Tags: oracle

Hi I have selected the following columns from various tables using left join and i am getting the following result.

```
Box_ID    BOX_NAME  VALUE  PROM_EFFDATE       PROM_CLOSEDATE

11      JE 1        115    2/27/2014    
11      JE 2        80     2/27/2014              3/6/2014
11      JE 4        60     2/17/2014    
11      JE 3
```

If the PROM_CLOSEDATE have some value, then the equivalent BOX_NAME(JE2) should be shown once again with null value and null effdate. We can enter any other different value for different periodic time.
This is the actual requirement. the result should be:

```
Box_ID    BOX_NAME  VALUE  PROM_EFFDATE       PROM_CLOSEDATE

    11      JE 1        115    2/27/2014    
    11      JE 2        80     2/27/2014              3/6/2014
    11      JE 2                          
    11      JE 4        60     2/17/2014    
    11      JE 3
```

like that i have to get the value.

Here I have used as per san's guidance,

```
SELECT Box_ID,BOX_NAME, VALUE, PROM_EFFDATE, PROM_CLOSEDATE
  FROM tab
UNION
SELECT Box_ID,BOX_NAME, NULL, NULL, NULL 
 FROM tab
WHERE PROM_CLOSEDATE IS NOT NULL
order by 2
```

But i want the result with more precise. when i enter the value and effective date (without giving CLOSE_DATE) for JE2(2nd ) Occurance, that time i am getting the following output.

```
Box_ID    BOX_NAME  VALUE  PROM_EFFDATE       PROM_CLOSEDATE

        11      JE 1        115    2/27/2014    
        11      JE 2        80     2/27/2014              3/6/2014
        11      JE 2        90     4/6/2014           
        11      JE 2                          
        11      JE 4        60     2/17/2014    
        11      JE 3
```

But actually, i dont need the record with NULL value, NULL effective date, NULL closedate when the BOX_NAME(here JE2) has record with no Closedate.
I need only when it has record with closedate is NOT NULL case. Even it has record with value, effective date and no closedate, the null record should not come. 
This is my requirement. Please Help me to get the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is by using union all

```
WITH tab(Box_ID,BOX_NAME, VALUE, PROM_EFFDATE, PROM_CLOSEDATE) AS (
SELECT 11,'JE 1',115,'2/27/2014', NULL FROM dual UNION ALL   
SELECT 11,'JE 2', 80,'2/27/2014','3/6/2014' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 11,'JE 2', 90,'2/28/2014','3/7/2014' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 11,'JE 4', 60,'2/17/2014', NULL  FROM dual UNION ALL    
SELECT 11,'JE 3', NULL, NULL, NULL  FROM dual)
----------
--End of data preparation
----------
SELECT Box_ID,BOX_NAME, VALUE, PROM_EFFDATE, PROM_CLOSEDATE
  FROM tab
UNION
SELECT Box_ID,BOX_NAME, NULL, NULL, NULL 
 FROM tab
WHERE PROM_CLOSEDATE IS NOT NULL
order by 2
```

Output:

```
| BOX_ID | BOX_NAME |  VALUE | PROM_EFFDATE | PROM_CLOSEDATE |
|--------|----------|--------|--------------|----------------|
|     11 |     JE 1 |    115 |    2/27/2014 |         (null) |
|     11 |     JE 2 |     80 |    2/27/2014 |       3/6/2014 |
|     11 |     JE 2 | (null) |       (null) |         (null) |
|     11 |     JE 3 | (null) |       (null) |         (null) |
|     11 |     JE 4 |     60 |    2/17/2014 |         (null) |
```

Comment: So what? Just use the select part after `End of data preparation` and replace `tab` with your table name. It will work for all records present in your table.

Comment: In that case, you can either use `distinct` in the second select  as `select distinct Box_ID,BOX_NAME, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM tab` or replace `union all` with `union`.

Comment: Updated the post as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you san. union is working well. In this table PROM_EFFDATE is only mandatory field. we can save without giving PROM_CLOSEDATE. When we save record without giving PROM_CLOSEDATE, the null value record should not be added. this is my requirement. But it adds the  null record due to the PROM_CLOSEDATE value which we added already. What should i do. Can you please help me??

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Box_ID,BOX_NAME, VALUE, PROM_EFFDATE, PROM_CLOSEDATE
  FROM tab
UNION
SELECT Box_ID,BOX_NAME, NULL, NULL, NULL 
 FROM tab
WHERE (PROM_CLOSEDATE IS NOT NULL 
AND PROM_EFFDATE IS NOT NULL) AND
(PROM_CLOSEDATE IS NULL 
AND PROM_EFFDATE IS NOT NULL)
order by 2
```

This code will work