# Hashtable output repeats in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have tried the following code to bind the hashtable with listbox.

***.aspx:***

```
 <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Hashtable.aspx.vb" Inherits="Hashtable" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
            <br />
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox><br />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***.aspx.vb***

```vb
    #Region "Namespaces"

    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Net.Mail

    #End Region
    Partial Class Hashtable
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim ht As New Hashtable
            ht.Items.Add("1", "Sunday")
            ht.Items.Add("2", "Monday")
            ht.Items.Add("3", "Tuesday")
            ht.Items.Add("4", "Wednesday")
            ht.Items.Add("5", "Thursday")
            ht.Items.Add("6", "Friday")
            ht.Items.Add("7", "Saturday")

            For Each item In ht.Items

                ListBox1.Items.Add(item.key)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(item.value)

            Next    

        End Sub
    End Class
```

When executing, I got the following output:

in listbox,

```
 1 Sunday 2 Monday 3 Tuesday 4 Wednesday 5 Thursday 6 Friday 7 Saturday
 1 Sunday 2 Monday 3 Tuesday 4 Wednesday 5 Thursday 6 Friday 7 Saturday
```

Why is it appearing twice when I have used a single loop in my code? And what can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question today few hours ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823534/how-can-i-get-the-duplicate-value-in-oracle If the answer did not work for you, please comment or update your question there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
select box_id,box_refid,box_value,effdate,closedate
from box_percent
union all
select box_id,box_refid,null,null,null
from box_percent
where closedate is not null
```

Comment: Dear simon.,thankyou soooooooooo much.It works very very very well. I am happy so much